# Unit calculator with more variables

Tags: javascript, php, calculator

I'm trying to make unit conversion calculator using php, basically, it'll change the value of 2 select menus base on the main select menu, which I able to do using javascript, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to approach this in php. In the main select menu load different values base on the material you select even though we are using the same units. I appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction or share some sample codes.

What I wanted to achieve https://alkoutprojects.com/customer-support/conversion-calculator/
in below format.

[image]

```
        <div class="container html-top form-group">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Conversion Calculator</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post" class="html-top">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 no-gutters padding-left">
                        <label for="Material">Materials</label><br>
                        <select id="type" class="form-control">
                        <option value="item0">Select a material</option>
                            <option value="32% NaoH">32% NaoH</option>
                            <option value="50% NaoH">50% NaoH</option>
                            <option value="6% Hypo">6% Hypo</option>
                            <option value="12% Hypo">12% Hypo</option>
                            <option value="chlorine">Chlorine</option>
                            <option value="hcl">Hcl</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4"> 
                        <label for="">From UDM: </label><br>
                        <select id="fdm" class="form-control">

                                 <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4 padding-right">   
                        <label for="">To UDM: </label><br>
                        <select id="tdm" class="form-control">

                                 <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>      
                </div><!--/row-->
                    </br>
                <div class="row">   
                    <label for="insertvalue">Insert Value</label></br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="row">   
                    <label for="insertvalue">Answer</label></br>
                    <input type="text" value="Answer" class="form-control" readonly>

                </div>              
                </br>
                <div class="row padding-left no-gutters">
                <button value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary margin-left">Submit</button>
                </div>





            </form>

        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#type").change(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val == "32% NaoH") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='$val1'>M3</option><option value='$val2'>MT</option><option value='$val3'>Liter</option>");
                } else if (val == "50% NaoH") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option>");
                } else if (val == "6% Hypo") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option><option value='Liter'>Liter</option>");
                } else if (val == "12% Hypo") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option><option value='Liter'>Liter</option>");
                } else if (val == "chlorine") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option>");
                } else if (val == "hcl") {
                    $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option> <option value='MT'>MT</option> <option value='Imperial Gallon'>Imperial Gallon</option> <option value='US Gallon'>US Gallon</option> <option value='liter'>liter</option>  ");
                }

            });
    });
    </script>
    </body>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYAf5.jpg
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, i'd recommend looking up AJAX. Basically send your form data into separate php to do the calculation and return with answer.

Comment: If JS is already involved, using PHP would adds unnecessary complexity. Why not just do all the calculations on the client side with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another approach and got the results I needed, Thank you very much for your time and effort it really helps me to narrow things down. My final code is below.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

$number = $_POST['number'];
$fdm = $_POST['fdm'];
$tdm = $_POST['tdm'];

        if($fdm == '32m3' && $tdm  == '32mt'){
            $answer = $number * 5 . 'MT';
        }elseif($fdm == '32m3' && $tdm  == '32l'){
            $answer = $number * 10 . 'L';
        }

        else{
            $answer = "Wrong data combination";
        }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Conversion Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container html-top form-group">
                <h2 class="text-center html-top">Conversion Calculator</h2>
        <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post" id="calculations">
            <!--<form action="#" method="post" id="calculations">-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 no-gutters padding-left">
                    <label for="Material">Materials</label><br>
                    <select id="type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="item0">Select a material</option>
                        <option value="32% NaoH">32% NaoH</option>
                        <option value="50% NaoH">50% NaoH</option>
                        <option value="6% Hypo">6% Hypo</option>
                        <option value="12% Hypo">12% Hypo</option>
                        <option value="chlorine">Chlorine</option>
                        <option value="hcl">Hcl</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <label for="">From UDM: </label><br>
                    <select name="fdm" id="fdm" class="form-control">
                             <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                    </select>

                </div>

                <div class="col-4 padding-right">   
                    <label for="">To UDM: </label><br>
                    <select name="tdm" id="tdm" class="form-control">

                             <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                    </select>
                </div>      
            </div><!--/row-->
                </br>
            <div class="row">   
                <label for="insertvalue">Insert Value</label></br>
                <input id="number" name="number" required type="text" class="form-control">

            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">   
                <label for="insertvalue">Convert Value</label></br>             
                <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value="<?php echo (isset($answer))?$answer:'';?>" class="form-control" readonly>

            </div>              
            </br>
            <div class="row padding-left no-gutters">
            <button value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary margin-left">Submit</button> 
            <a class="btn btn-secondary margin-left-button" href="index.php">Reset</a>
            </div>


        </form>

    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#type").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "32% NaoH") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='32m3'>M3</option><option value='32mt'>MT</option><option value='32l'>Liter</option>");
            } else if (val == "50% NaoH") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='50m3'>M3</option><option value='50mt'>MT</option>");
            } else if (val == "6% Hypo") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option><option value='Liter'>Liter</option>");
            } else if (val == "12% Hypo") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option><option value='Liter'>Liter</option>");
            } else if (val == "chlorine") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option><option value='MT'>MT</option>");
            } else if (val == "hcl") {
                $("#fdm,#tdm").html("<option value='M3'>M3</option> <option value='MT'>MT</option> <option value='Imperial Gallon'>Imperial Gallon</option> <option value='US Gallon'>US Gallon</option> <option value='liter'>liter</option>  ");
            }


        });
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("calculations").reset();
    }    
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PHP is server-rendered, so if you do it in PHP, then it would be something like this:

- The user inserts a value in a field
- And then presses 'Submit'
- The inputted value is then sent to the server (where the PHP is executed)
- The calculations are then being done and returns a value, which is sent back to the browser.

It could look something like this:

```
<?php
if( !empty( $_POST['one_value'] ){
  $one_value = $_POST['one_value'];
  $calculated_value = $one_value * 100; 
} else {
  $calculated_value = 'No value was calculated';
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post"> 
  <input type="text" name="one_value" value="Insert a number value here" />
  <input type="text" name="calculated_value" value="<?php echo $calculated_value; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="CALCULATE" />
</form>
```

I haven't tested it, - but if you insert a number-value in the first field and press 'submit', then you should see the value multiplied with 100 afterwards in the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an **on change event** for the 'main' drop down and upon changing, generate the other values for the drop downs.

**Example:**

```
$( "#mainSelect" ).change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    //now you compare the value and generate the other 2 drop downs.
    //(Just showing one comparison, you can do the other else if statements)

    if (val == "32% NaoH") {
        //First remove the options that is currently in the select
        $("#fdm option").remove();
        //Now you can add the options for the select as you want to.
        $("#fdm").append('<option value="yourValue">yourText</option>');
        //Do the same for your second select
        $("#tdm option").remove();
        $("#tdm").append('<option value="yourValue">yourText</option>');
    } 
});
```

This using pure jQuery. If you want to make use of some PHP (You don't have to), you can do what @yasoh commented on your question.

I hope I made sense and was of help. Goodluck!

**EDITED:**

*HTML:*

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="calculations">
    <select name="firstSelect">
        <option value="value1">value1Text</option>
        <option value="value2">value2Text</option>
        <option value="value3">value3Text</option>
    </select>
    <select name="secondSelect">
        <option value="value1">value1Text</option>
        <option value="value2">value2Text</option>
        <option value="value3">value3Text</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="POST VALUES">
</form>
```

*jQuery: (ajax request)*

```
$('#calculations').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#calculations');
     $.ajax({
         url: '/includes/do_calculations.php',
         data: form.serialize(),
         dataType: 'JSON',
         type: "POST",
         success: function(data) {
             if (data.status == "Success") {
                 var answer = data.answer; //getting the answer variable from the back-end.
             }
                },
            });
        })
```

*back-end:*

Grab the values like this in the back-end:

```
$firstValue = trim(strip_tags($_POST['firstSelect']));
$secondValue = trim(strip_tags($_POST['secondSelect']));

$answer = $firstValue + $secondValue; //Just an example
```

Now you can use the values in the variables to do your calculations as needed. Once you are done you can just echo it back.

```
$response['status'] = 'Success';
$response['answer'] = $answer; // You are posting the answer back and then you can use it in your front-end again.
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Hi Don, in the code I share I can load values to other 2 select meus correctly depend on the material you select but my issue is for example 32%NaoH M3,MT vales are not same as 50%NaoH M3, MT values, so what I need is check 4 paramerts and do the calulation 1- selected matarial, 2-From UDM, 3- To Udm and 4-the value then result will depend on all this 4, that's why I need php, Do you know any other way only using jquery?

Comment: Hi Roshan, the best alternative is to make use of an ajax request. Submit the values for each select to your sever-side page and to the calculations/checks there. Return the answer/value back to the front-end. I am going to edit my answer to show you an example of what I am trying to explain.